# a sketchy person has my phone for half an hour. what should i look for?

Tags: security, malware, privacy

Summary: what sketchy things, could someone do if they get your phone for half an hour. And could you do to find it out and protect yourself.

Luckily, nothing happened for me.

Comment: Hi, while I could sympathize with the situation, the question is too broad to be answered; without specific details, we can't suggest anything other than "change your passwords and do a factory reset for safety precaution". Being a Q&A site, Stack Exchange works best if you have a very specific problem with sufficient details. Sorry, but perhaps try other forums like XDA Forums or Reddits which allows more open-ended back-and-forth troubleshooting.

Comment: check your data usage for unkown apps. remove all google accounts including your own, create a new one for this device. inform your contacts that wasn't you last night (in case he sent something). uninstall automation apps like tasker, macrodroid (if any)

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous things that one can do in half-an-hour. There are some things that you have little or no control over now, like him sharing your images and data, or him uploading your personal data to a place where he can access it later. There is also a risk of him having your passwords and credentials, because we usually use auto-fill services, or tend to save them in a note-taking app. Other possibilities include him installing a spyware on your phone.

The measures that you can take to re-secure yourself are:

1. **Change all the passwords**, particularly your banking passwords.
2. Take a look at your installed apps, and **check if there exists any app that you haven't installed**
3. If you use Google Photos, or a similar photo app which has a 'shared account' feature, you might want to **ensure that no unauthorized person** is added to it, since the person may have access to your photos
4. Review the **login activity of your accounts** (social media, etc.), and ensure that only authorized devices are logged in.
5. Check the **running services of your phone** and ensure that no 'shady' service is running. ([How to check running services in Android](https://www.nexmobility.com/articles/background-apps-making-your-android-slow.html)

**I would advise you not to give unauthorized people access to your  devices. Our devices store a lot of 'sensitive' information which may be stolen, and misused. Also, if it is inevitable, you might want to limit the privileges (by using a guest account).**